# OpenLayers: ModifyFeature not working

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I just want that i can modify my lines.
But although the onModificationStart is fired, the mode is set to RESHAPE, the correct layer is set and createVertices is set to true, it just looks like a normal selection, without any circles for the modification.

I have deactived ANY other controls (tons of SelectFeatures and DrawFeatures, HighlightFeature etc.), but nothing!
I also looked up the OpenLayers-Example.

Are there any specific things to pay attention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible explanation: your layer may have style, where point symbols are not visible. Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/jSQrj/11/

Comment out line

```
pointRadius: 6
```

As result, style will be incorrect for point objects, and handlers won't be visible for selected feature (usually it's better to extend default styles with OpenLayers.Util.extend, instead of solution, that is in example).

Comment: Big thanks! I used custom style maps and there pointRadius was not even defined!